# $\int f_kd\mu_k\to\int fd\mu$?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, weak-convergence

If a measure $\mu_k$ converges weakly to a measure $\mu$, i.e. $\int fd\mu_k\to \int fd\mu$ for every $f\in C_b(\mathbb{R})$ (contiuous and bounded functions), and let $f_k\to f$ a.e. pointwise. Then I was wondering what extra condition we need so that $\int f_kd\mu_k\to\int fd\mu$. I have $$\int f_kd\mu_k=\underbrace{\int fd\mu_k}_{\to\int fd\mu}+\int (f_k-f)d\mu_k$$ but I am not sure when the second term goes to zero.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by $f_k\to f$ a.e. pointwise? Only for a finite number of points it doesn't converge?

Comment: @Maxence1402 I think it means that the set of $x$ such that $f_k(x) \not\to f(x)$ has measure $0$.

Comment: @GiorgosGiapitzakis Of course, but for which measure?

Answer (score 3):

Even if $\mu_k=\mu$, a.e. convergence of $f_k$ to $f$ is not sufficient to guarantee convergence of the integral. As an example take a non-zero positive function $\phi\in C_c(\mathbb{R})$ with support in $(0,1)$ and let $f_k(x)=k\phi(kx)$. Then $f_k\to 0$ pointwise, but
$$
\int_0^1 f_k(x)\,dx=\int_0^k \phi(x)\,dx=\int_0^1 \phi(x)\,dx>0.
$$
(The measure $\mu$ here is the uniform measure on $(0,1)$.)

The claimed convergence is true for all weakly convergent sequences $(\mu_k)$ if and only if $(f_k)$ is uniformly bounded and $f_k\to f$ uniformly on compact sets:

Every weakly convergent sequence of finite measures is bounded by the uniform boundedness principle. Moreover, it is tight, that is, for every $\epsilon>0$ there exist $R>0$ and $N\in \mathbb N$ such that $\mu_k(\mathbb R\setminus[-R,R])<\epsilon$ for all $k\geq N$. If $(f_k)$ is uniformly bounded and $f_k\to f$ uniformly on compact sets, then
\begin{align*}
\left\lvert\int (f-f_k)\,d\mu_k\right\rvert&\leq \left\lvert\int_{\mathbb R\setminus[-R,R]}(f-f_k)\,d\mu_k\right\rvert+\left\lvert\int_{[-R,R]}(f-f_k)\,d\mu_k\right\rvert\\
&\leq 2\epsilon\sup_j \|f_j\|_\infty+\sup_{|x|\leq R}|f(x)-f_k(x)|\cdot\sup_{j}\|\mu_j\|,
\end{align*}
which gives the desired convergence.

For the converse implication, the uniform boundedness follows from the uniform boundedness principle. Now assume $(f_k)$ does not converge uniformly on compact sets to $f$, that is, there exist $R>0$, $\epsilon>0$, a subsequence $(f_{k_n})$ of $(f_k)$ and a sequence $(x_n)$ in $[-R,R]$ such that $|f(x_n)-f_{k_n}(x_n)|\geq \epsilon$.

Since $[-R,R]$ is compact, there exists a subsequence of $(x_n)$ that converges to some $x\in [-R,R]$. To avoid even more indices, I'll just assume that $(x_n)$ itself converges. This means that also $\delta_{x_n}\to \delta_x$ weakly.

Since $f$ is continuous, there exists $N\in \mathbb N$ such that $|f(x)-f(x_n)|<\epsilon/2$ for $n\geq N$. Thus
$$
\left\lvert\int f\,d\delta(x)-\int f_n\,d\delta(x_n)\right\rvert\geq |f(x_n)-f_n(x_n)|-|f(x)-f(x_n)|\geq \epsilon/2
$$
in contradiction to our assumption.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Could you expand a bit on "Every weakly convergent sequence of finite measures is bounded by the uniform boundedness principle". I just looked it ([uniform boundedness principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_boundedness_principle)) up and I was wondering what Banach space are you considering and which version of the theorem you are using. Is it "Any weakly bounded subset S in a normed space Y is bounded"?

Comment: Every (finite) measure defines an element in the dual of $C_b(\mathbb{R})$ by integration, and the pointwise boundedness is a consequence of the weak convergence. Btw, you'll need the measures to be defined on the Borel $\sigma$-algebra for this answer (and also Oliver Diaz's) to be true.

Comment: So would it be correct to say that the collection we are considering in Banach-Steinhaus is $=\{\mu_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$? To show pointwise boundedness we would need to show |$⟨\mu_n,\phi⟩|≤M∀\phi∈_b(\mathbb{R})$ where $⟨\mu_n,\phi⟩=\int\phi d\mu_n$. And since $⟨\mu_n,\phi⟩→⟨\mu,\phi⟩$ and this is a sequence of real values, we have the boundedness (because a converging sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ is bounded). Then the conclusion of Banach-Steinhaus would be $\sup_{‖‖≤1}\int\phi d\mu_n≤$ for every $n$?

Comment: oh, I get it. $\sup_{\|\phi\|\le 1}\int\phi d\mu_n$ is the norm of $\mu_n$ as an operaor but by Riesz representation this is the same as the norm of $\mu_n$ (in total variation) as a measure. So in the end we get $\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\|\mu_n\|_{_{TV}}\le C<+\infty$

Answer (score 3):

Some equicontinuity property along with uniform integrability is enough. Here is a result by Mann, Wald, Prokhorov, Rubin (see, ***Kallenberg, O. Foundations of probability, second ed. Springer. 2001, pp. 76***)

> Suppose  $(S,d)$ and $(T,\rho)$ are  metric spaces, $\{X_n,X:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ are random variables taking values in $S$ such that  $X_n\stackrel{law}{=}\mu_n\stackrel{n}{\Longrightarrow}\mu\stackrel{law}{=} X$. If $(f_n,f:n\in\mathbb{N})$ are measurable functions from $S$ into  $T$, and there is a measurable set $C\subset S$ such that
>
> 1. $\operatorname{supp}\mu\subset C$, and
> 2. $f_n(s_n)\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}f(s)$ for any $s_n\rightarrow s\in C$.
>
> Then $f_n(X_n)\stackrel{n}{\Longrightarrow} f(X)$, that is $$\int g(f_n(X_n))dP=\int_S g(f_n(x))\,\mu_n(dx)\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_S g(f(x))\,\mu(dx)=\int g(f(X))\,dP$$  for all $g\in\mathcal{C}_b(T)$.

If $T=\mathbb{R}$, and the sequence $(f_n(X_n):n\in\mathbb{N})$ is uniformly integrable, then you may use $g(t)=t$ to get the convergence you are looking for, that is $$\int f(x)\,\mu_n(dx)\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}\int f(x)\,\mu(dx)$$
(See ***Billingsley, Convergence of Probability measures, Wiley 1968, Theorem 5.4)***

---

A slightly more general version of the result above can be found in ***van der Vaart, A.W. Asymptotic statistics, Cambridge 1998, pp. 258-259*** where some measurability assumptions are dropped and the integrals are "upper" integrals (upper Daniell integrals).

In both references, the proof of the statements relay on the Portmanteau theorem.

Comment: Thank you, I am consulting the references

Comment: Late follow up question : if $T=\mathbb{R}$ then $g(t)=t$ is not in $C_b(T)$ no? So we cannot apply the result no?

Comment: That is correct; however, under some additional hypothesis, say uniform integrability, one can get results for moments (i.e. g(x)=x).

Comment: Do you have a typo (missing lower case $n$ in the convergence). I couldn't correct it since it is just one character.

Comment: As you mention, condition 2 looks like some kind of sequential equi-continuity even though I would have said that sequential equi-continuity would have been $f_n(x_k)\to f_n(x)$ when $k\to\infty \forall n\in\mathbb{N}$. Both these conditions are not the same right?